# Is it possible to merge duplicate labels (and their datas) into one column in Chart Js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, chart.js

For example, if I have the array ['05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019'] for Labels and the array ['2', '5', '7', '4'] for their respective values.

Is it possible to show only one column for all the elements '05/Feb/2019', summing up their values in this column?

## CODE FOR CHART JS

```
myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"),{
    "type":temp.type,
    "data":{
        "labels":column_a,
        "datasets":[{
            "label":label_b,
            "data":column_b,
            "spanGaps": true,
            "fill":false,//true for charts like radar and polar area
            "backgroundColor":["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)","rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)","rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.4)","rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)","rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)","rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)","rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.4)"],
            "borderWidth":1
            }
            ]},
            "options":{
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (tooltipItem, myChart) => {
                            const realValue = myChart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                            //const customValue = realValue.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + '%';
                            const customValue = realValue.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
                            const label = myChart.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ':';
                            return label + customValue;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                "scales":{
                    "yAxes":[{
                        "gridLines":{display:false},
                        "ticks":{
                            "suggestedMin":0,
                            "max":max_value_1
                        }}]}
                        }});
window.myChart = myChart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use reduce for this. May this helps you !

```
 var label = ['05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019'];
    var value = ['2', '5', '7', '4'];

    var obj = label.reduce(function(a, b, i) {
        if(!a.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
            a[b] = 0;
        }
        console.log(a);
        a[b] += Number(value[i]);
         return a;
    },{});

    var lab = Object.keys(obj);
    var val = Object.values(obj);
```

Comment: This successfully did the job, but now the chart does not render anymore. I have tried using .map() and .split(), but none of them helped it rendering either.

Comment: btw, the label in your code is my column_a (sometimes known as legend for charts). The value is the column_b in my code.

Comment: I have found the issue: there is a NaN at the end of the array:  6.35,9.07,78.93,12420.514,198.67,0.91,34.02,13.15,59.42,302.06,1480.94,62.099999999999994,111.52,303.88,90.71000000000001,11516.993999999999,84.78000000000002,130.51999999999998,253.54000000000002,189.45,1.35,3.62,22.209999999999997,215.45,1.8,738.94,6.35,0.36,2.72,NaN

Comment: Solved!! I had to remove the NaN using ".filter(Boolean)". After that, I changed "const" to "var" for my "column_b". Issue solved. Thank you, Saurabh!

Comment: just noticed that in some cases, the first label and value are not taken into account with the others, So for example, I end up with the following output: ARRAY (labels) ['05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019'] and ARRAY (values) ['2', '12', '4'] for their respective values. Do you know why this is happening?